# Assigning classes

Tags: r, classification, lda

I need to generate data with 2 predictors and 3 classes, where the distribution in each class follows a normal distribution with its own mean vector, and common covariance matrix across all classes.

I generated the data. Now I am not sure how I can assign 3 different classes in R. 
I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
x1 = mvrnorm(50, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 3), 2)) 

x2 = mvrnorm(50, mu = c(3, 3), Sigma = matrix(c(4, 0, 0, 1), 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like a start, except that the two groups of points that you generated have *different* covariance matrices, despite your words that say that they should be the same.  The words also say to generate three classes. The points in x1 will be in class 1, x2 in class 2, etc.  So you can use something like this.

```
library(MASS)

set.seed(123)
x1 = mvrnorm(50, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 3), 2)) 
x2 = mvrnorm(50, mu = c(3, 3), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 3), 2))
x3 = mvrnorm(50, mu = c(1, 6), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 3), 2))

DAT = rbind(x1,x2,x3)
Class = col=rep(2:4, each=50)

plot(DAT, pch=20, col=Class)
```

[image: Three classes]